# Can not unmarshall the SOAP response

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, unmarshalling, stringreader

I could send a request and receive the response but I can not parse the response. It returns the following error:

```
Local Name:Body
error is here
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ticketmaster.ticketmaster.TicketMaster.Search(TicketMaster.java:119)
    at com.ticketmaster.ticketmaster.App.main(App.java:12)
```

**Code**

```
    SOAPMessage response
            = connection.call(message, endpoint);

    connection.close();
        SOAPMessage sm = response;
        SOAPBody sb = response.getSOAPBody();
        System.err.println("Node Name:" + sb.getNodeName());  //return nothing
        System.err.println("Local Name:" + sb.getLocalName());  //return Local Name:Body

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(sb);
        results = (FindEventsResponse) JAXB.unmarshal(source, FindEventsResponse.class);
        System.err.println("Results size: " + this.results.returnTag.results.item.get(0).getName());

} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println("error is here");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Response:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                   xmlns:ns1="http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php" 
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
                   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:findEventsResponse>
            <return xsi:type="ns1:Response">
                <details xsi:type="ns1:Details">
                    <totalResults xsi:type="xsd:int">20662</totalResults>
                    <totalPages xsi:type="xsd:int">414</totalPages>
                    <currentPage xsi:type="xsd:int">1</currentPage>
                    <resultsPerPage xsi:type="xsd:int">50</resultsPerPage>
                </details>
                <results SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:Event[50]" xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfEvent">
                    <item xsi:type="ns1:Event">
                        <eventId xsi:type="xsd:int">1516682</eventId>
                        <ticketmasterEventId xsi:type="xsd:string">18004C6E8D7218A8</ticketmasterEventId>
                        <status xsi:type="xsd:string">onSale</status>
                        <name xsi:type="xsd:string">The Art of the Brick</name>
                        <url xsi:type="xsd:string">http://www.ticketmaster.ie/event/18004C6E8D7218A8?camefrom=CFC_UK_BUYAT&amp;brand=[=BRAND=]</url>
                        <eventDate xsi:type="xsd:string">2014-05-23 10:00:00</eventDate>
                        <onSaleDate xsi:type="xsd:string">0000-00-00 00:00:00</onSaleDate>
                        <preSaleDate xsi:type="xsd:string">0000-00-00 00:00:00</preSaleDate>
                        <category xsi:type="xsd:string">Exhibitions</category>
                        <categoryId xsi:type="xsd:int">754</categoryId>
                        <parentCategory xsi:type="xsd:string">Family &amp;amp; Attractions</parentCategory>
                        <parentCategoryId xsi:type="xsd:int">10003</parentCategoryId>
                        <minPrice xsi:type="xsd:float">17</minPrice>
                        <maxPrice xsi:type="xsd:float">17</maxPrice>
                        <artists SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:Artist[1]" xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfArtist">
                            <item xsi:type="ns1:Artist">
                                <artistId xsi:type="xsd:int">1806028</artistId>
                                <ticketmasterArtistId xsi:type="xsd:int">1663495</ticketmasterArtistId>
                                <name xsi:type="xsd:string">The Art of the Brick</name>
                                <url xsi:type="xsd:string">http://www.ticketmaster.co.uk/The-Art-of-the-Brick-tickets/artist/1663495?camefrom=CFC_UK_BUYAT&amp;brand=[=BRAND=]</url>
                                <imageUrl xsi:type="xsd:string">http://media.ticketmaster.com/tm/en-us/tmimages/TM_GenCatImgs_Generic_BW.jpg</imageUrl>
                                <category xsi:type="xsd:string">Miscellaneous</category>
                                <categoryId xsi:type="xsd:int">0</categoryId>
                                <parentCategory xsi:type="xsd:string">Miscellaneous</parentCategory>
                                <parentCategoryId xsi:type="xsd:int">10005</parentCategoryId>
                            </item>
                        </artists>
                        <venue xsi:type="ns1:Venue">
                            <venueId xsi:type="xsd:int">3331</venueId>
                            <ticketmasterVenueId xsi:type="xsd:int">198292</ticketmasterVenueId>
                            <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Ambassador Theatre</name>
                            <street xsi:type="xsd:string">Oconnell Street</street>
                            <city xsi:type="xsd:string">Dublin</city>
                            <country xsi:type="xsd:string">United Kingdom</country>
                            <postcode xsi:type="xsd:string">Dublin 1</postcode>
                            <url xsi:type="xsd:string">http://www.ticketmaster.ie/Ambassador-Theatre-tickets-Dublin/venue/198292?camefrom=CFC_UK_BUYAT&amp;brand=</url>
                            <imageUrl xsi:type="xsd:string">http://media.ticketmaster.co.uk/tmimages/TM_GenVenueImg_BW.jpg</imageUrl>
                            <state xsi:type="xsd:string"></state>
                        </venue>
                    </item>
                    <item xsi:type="ns1:Event">
                     ....
```

**Model Classes**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FindEventsResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "return")
    Return returnTag;

    public FindEventsResponse() {
       this.returnTag = new Return();
    }
    getter and setter

}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Return {
    @XmlElement(name = "details")
    Details details;
    @XmlElement(name = "results")
    Results results;

    public Return(Details details, Results results) {
       this.details = new Details();
       this.results = new Results();
    }
    getters and setters


}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Details {

    @XmlElement(name = "totalResults")
    int totalResults;
    @XmlElement(name = "totalPages")
    int totalPages;
    @XmlElement(name = "currentPage")
    int currentPage;
    @XmlElement(name = "resultPerPage")
    int resultsPerPage;

     getters and setters

}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Results {
    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    List<Item> item;

    public Results() {
       this.item = new ArrayList();
    }
    getter and setter



}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    @XmlElement(name = "eventId")
    int eventId;
    @XmlElement(name = "ticketmasterEventId")
    String ticketmasterEventId;
    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    String status;
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "url")
    String url;
    @XmlElement(name = "eventDate")
    String eventDate;
    @XmlElement(name = "onSaleDate")
    String onSaleDate;
    @XmlElement(name = "preSaleDate")
    String preSaleDate;
    @XmlElement(name = "category")
    String category;
    @XmlElement(name = "categoryId")
    int categoryId;
    @XmlElement(name = "parentCategory")
    String parentCategory;
    @XmlElement(name = "parentCategoryId")
    int parentCategoryId;
    @XmlElement(name = "minPrice")
    int minPrice;
    @XmlElement(name = "maxPrice")
    int maxPrice;
    @XmlElement(name = "artists")
    private Artists artist;
    @XmlElement(name = "venue")
    private Venue venue;

    public Item() {
       this.artist = new Artists();
       this.venue = new Venue();
    }

    getters and setters

}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Artists {
    @XmlElement(name = "artists")
    private ArtistItem item;

    public Artists() {
        this.item = new ArtistItem();
    }
    getter and setter
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ArtistItem {

    @XmlElement(name = "artistId")
    int artistId;
    @XmlElement(name = "ticketmasterArtistsId")
    int ticketmasterArtistId;
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "url")
    String url;
    @XmlElement(name = "imageUrl")
    String imageUrl;
    @XmlElement(name = "category")
    String category;
    @XmlElement(name = "categoryId")
    int categoryId;
    @XmlElement(name = "parentCategory")
    String parentCategory;
    @XmlElement(name = "parentCategoryId")
    int parentCategoryId;

    getters and setters
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Venue {

    @XmlElement(name = "venueId")
    int venueId;
    @XmlElement(name = "ticketmasterVenueId")
    int ticketmasterVenueId;
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "street")
    String street;
    @XmlElement(name = "city")
    String city;
    @XmlElement(name = "country")
    String country;
    @XmlElement(name = "postcode")
    String postcode;
    @XmlElement(name = "url")
    String url;
    @XmlElement(name = "imageUrl")
    String imageUrl;
    @XmlElement(name = "state")
    String state;

    getters and setters
}
```

Based on one of the following answers, I marshalled the result and it shows a wrong response.

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED) 
package com.ticketmaster.ticketmaster;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**Code**

```
    SOAPBody sb = response.getSOAPBody();
System.err.println(">>"+ sb.getFirstChild().getNodeName());
Iterator itr = sb.getChildElements();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    Object element = itr.next();
    System.err.println(element + " ");
}
Document d = sb.extractContentAsDocument();
System.err.println("result of d:"+d.getTextContent());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(d);
results = (FindEventsResponse) JAXB.unmarshal(source, FindEventsResponse.class);
System.err.println("results>"+results.getReturnTag().getResults().getItem().get(0).getName());
```

**Error is**

```
.....
><city xsi:type="xsd:string">London</city><country xsi:type="xsd:string">United Kingdom</country><postcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SE1 8XX</postcode><url xsi:type="xsd:string">http://www.ticketmaster.co.uk/The-London-Wonderground-tickets-London/venue/253993?camefrom=CFC_UK_BUYAT&amp;brand=</url><imageUrl xsi:type="xsd:string">http://media.ticketmaster.co.uk/tmimages/TM_GenVenueImg_BW.jpg</imageUrl><state xsi:type="xsd:string"></state></venue></item></results></return></ns1:findEventsResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

>>ns1:findEventsResponse
[ns1:findEventsResponse: null] 
result of d:null
error is here

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix xsd is not bound to a namespace
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseQName(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:346)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyXsiLoader.selectLoader(LeafPropertyXsiLoader.java:75)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyXsiLoader.startElement(LeafPropertyXsiLoader.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:486)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:465)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:60)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:229)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:112)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:312)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:288)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:238)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(JAXB.java:259)
    at com.ticketmaster.ticketmaster.TicketMaster.Search(TicketMaster.java:132)
    at com.ticketmaster.ticketmaster.App.main(App.java:12)
```

Comment: Please, post TicketMaster code, in particular line 128.

Comment: @giorco question is updated, I also mentioned the line that is throwing the error.

Comment: Why you don't use some library to work with SOAP? [cxf](http://cxf.apache.org) for example.

Comment: @user1516873 is there any specific reason that you recommend cxf? I am not familiar with that.

Comment: @JackMoore no, not really, it is just one of many good open source library to work with web-services, with many features, with spring integration, and i personally use it last time to connect to service protected with ws-security. If you wish, you can look at Axis2 (last release in 2012) or Glassfish Metro.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Ensure You Are Unmarshalling the Correct Thing

You need to unmarshal the content held onto by **SOAP body**, not the entire **SOAP message**.  Below is what the code might look like:

```
SOAPMessage sm = response;
SOAPBody sb = response.getSOAPBody();
Document d = sb.extractContentAsDocument();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(d);
results = (FindEventsResponse) JAXB.unmarshal(source, FindEventsResponse.class);
```

The result of `sb.extractContentAsDocument` is going to be a DOM that is equivalent to the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:findEventsResponse xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <return xsi:type="ns1:Response">
        <details xsi:type="ns1:Details">
            <totalResults xsi:type="xsd:int">20662</totalResults>
            <totalPages xsi:type="xsd:int">414</totalPages>
            <currentPage xsi:type="xsd:int">1</currentPage>
            <resultsPerPage xsi:type="xsd:int">50</resultsPerPage>
        </details>
        <results SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:Event[50]" xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfEvent">
            <item xsi:type="ns1:Event">
                <eventId xsi:type="xsd:int">1516682</eventId>
                <ticketmasterEventId xsi:type="xsd:string">18004C6E8D7218A8</ticketmasterEventId>
                <status xsi:type="xsd:string">onSale</status>
                <name xsi:type="xsd:string">The Art of the Brick</name>
                <url xsi:type="xsd:string">http://www.ticketmaster.ie/event/18004C6E8D7218A8?camefrom=CFC_UK_BUYAT&amp;brand=[=BRAND=]</url>
                <eventDate xsi:type="xsd:string">2014-05-23 10:00:00</eventDate>
                <onSaleDate xsi:type="xsd:string">0000-00-00 00:00:00</onSaleDate>
                <preSaleDate xsi:type="xsd:string">0000-00-00 00:00:00</preSaleDate>
                <category xsi:type="xsd:string">Exhibitions</category>
                <categoryId xsi:type="xsd:int">754</categoryId>
                <parentCategory xsi:type="xsd:string">Family &amp;amp; Attractions</parentCategory>
                <parentCategoryId xsi:type="xsd:int">10003</parentCategoryId>
                <minPrice xsi:type="xsd:float">17</minPrice>
                <maxPrice xsi:type="xsd:float">17</maxPrice>
                <artists SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:Artist[1]" xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfArtist">
                    <item xsi:type="ns1:Artist">
                        <artistId xsi:type="xsd:int">1806028</artistId>
                        <ticketmasterArtistId xsi:type="xsd:int">1663495</ticketmasterArtistId>
                        <name xsi:type="xsd:string">The Art of the Brick</name>
                        <url xsi:type="xsd:string">http://www.ticketmaster.co.uk/The-Art-of-the-Brick-tickets/artist/1663495?camefrom=CFC_UK_BUYAT&amp;brand=[=BRAND=]</url>
                        <imageUrl xsi:type="xsd:string">http://media.ticketmaster.com/tm/en-us/tmimages/TM_GenCatImgs_Generic_BW.jpg</imageUrl>
                        <category xsi:type="xsd:string">Miscellaneous</category>
                        <categoryId xsi:type="xsd:int">0</categoryId>
                        <parentCategory xsi:type="xsd:string">Miscellaneous</parentCategory>
                        <parentCategoryId xsi:type="xsd:int">10005</parentCategoryId>
                    </item>
                </artists>
                <venue xsi:type="ns1:Venue">
                    <venueId xsi:type="xsd:int">3331</venueId>
                    <ticketmasterVenueId xsi:type="xsd:int">198292</ticketmasterVenueId>
                    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Ambassador Theatre</name>
                    <street xsi:type="xsd:string">Oconnell Street</street>
                    <city xsi:type="xsd:string">Dublin</city>
                    <country xsi:type="xsd:string">United Kingdom</country>
                    <postcode xsi:type="xsd:string">Dublin 1</postcode>
                    <url xsi:type="xsd:string">http://www.ticketmaster.ie/Ambassador-Theatre-tickets-Dublin/venue/198292?camefrom=CFC_UK_BUYAT&amp;brand=</url>
                    <imageUrl xsi:type="xsd:string">http://media.ticketmaster.co.uk/tmimages/TM_GenVenueImg_BW.jpg</imageUrl>
                    <state xsi:type="xsd:string"></state>
                </venue>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="ns1:Event"></item>
        </results>
    </return>
</ns1:findEventsResponse>
```

### UPDATE

Based on the new exception you are getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix xsd is not bound to a namespace
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseQName(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:346)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyXsiLoader.selectLoader(LeafPropertyXsiLoader.java:75)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyXsiLoader.startElement(LeafPropertyXsiLoader.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:486)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:465)
```

It appears as though `sb.extractContentAsDocument();` is not bringing along the `xmlns:xsd` declaration from the SOAP message.  Instead you can change the code to do the following:

```
SOAPMessage sm = response;
SOAPBody sb = response.getSOAPBody();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(sb.getFirstChild());
results = (FindEventsResponse) JAXB.unmarshal(source, FindEventsResponse.class);
```

## Ensure the Namespace Qualification is Mapped Correctly

Having the following tells JAXB that everything mapped to an XML element without an explicitly specified namespace should belong in the `http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php` namespace.

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package com.ticketmaster.ticketmaster;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

In your XML only the `findEventsResponse` element is namespace qualified.  This means your annotation should be the following instead (note change from `QUALIFIED` to `UNQUALIFIED`):

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED) 
package com.ticketmaster.ticketmaster;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

## Demo Code

Using the above XML as `input.xml` I was able to unmarshal and marshal the model as you have defined it in your question with the `@XmlSchema` fix mentioned above.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(FindEventsResponse.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("src/forum23806625/input.xml");
        JAXBElement<FindEventsResponse> response = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, FindEventsResponse.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(response, System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: it is still showing the same error message, question is updated.

Comment: @J888 - What element name corresponds to the `SOAPBody` in your example?  Also can you post the object model you are trying to unmarshal?

Comment: Sorry I do not get what you mean by element name corresponds to the SOAPBody? also what do you mean by the object model, is that the FindEventsResponse.class?

Comment: @J888 - What do you get when you call `getNodeName()` or `getLocalName()` on your instance of `SOAPBody`?  Can you post `FindEventsResponse`?  Also there are may objects accessed on the line throwing the `NullPointerException`.  Can you determine which object is `null`?

Comment: @J888 - If you populate your object model and marshal it out, what does the resulting XML look like?  Comparing that output to the input you are trying to unmarshal will be helpful.

Comment: buddy I could not find an answer, would you please have a look at the updated question. Thanks

Comment: @J888 - I have updated my answer with a lot of information that should help.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I changed my code as you mentioned but it runs into java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix xsd is not bound to a namespace , and when I change unqualified to qualified it does not return any error but the class of results is null. question is updated.

Comment: @J888 - Instead of `extractContentAsDocument` try calling `getFirstChild`.

Comment: firstChild node and value are name: ns1:findEventsResponse value: null

Comment: @J888 `getNodeValue()` on an element always returns `null`, see table in class comment for `Node`:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeValue().  Instead you need to inspect the child nodes.

Comment: Thanks, it is weird as I am able to show whole message but cannot show the children of response. Question is updated.

Comment: @J888 - What remaining issues are you having?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I reckon the question is updated, the following error is thrown java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix xsd is not bound to a namespace

Comment: @J888 - Are you still using `sb.extractContentAsDocument` what happens when you try calling `sb.getFirstChild` instead?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan output of getFirstChild is [ns1:findEventsResponse: null]

Comment: @J888 - What happens when you try to unmarshal a `DOMSource` on that `Element`?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan result of d.getTextContent() is null

Comment: @J888 - It won't have text content, but it will have child elements.  Can you try unmarshalling it?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I included the code in the question, it throws following exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix xsd is not bound to a namespace

Comment: @J888 - Your code is using `extractContentAsDocument` what happens when you replace that line with `getFirstChild`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55765/discussion-between-j888-and-blaise-doughan).

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan well done, please have a look at my question as well, I have already awarded the bounty for this one :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131822/parsed-soap-response-is-different-with-the-received-response

Comment: @JackMoore - Are you able to join this chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55765/discussion-between-j888-and-blaise-doughan